# woocommerce display categories/subcategories/products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

is there any way to display the main categories with subcategories and their products in woocommerce? php or shortcode?
I've tried with some conditional formatting,but nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two default shortcodes available to display both, product categories (with a specific parent category defined, to display subcategories,) and products contained inside a specific category.

To display top-level categories use the shortcode:

```
[product_categories parent="0"]
```

If you want to display subcategories, include the category ID inside the parent attribute.

To display products inside a category:

```
[product_category category="category-slug-here"]
```

Full reference for this shortcodes: [product categories shortcode](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-9) and [products in category shortcode](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-8)

Comment: I think I found the solution. This is what I was looking for. Unfortunately, it is an extension to Woocommerce. https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-nested-category-layout/