# Display Sub-categories of particular parent-category on home page in Wordpress woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to display Sub-categories of particular parent-category on home page in Wordpress woocommerce With there thumbnail images please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To display categories inside a category with thumbnail, add this short code in a widget / home page:

[product_categories parent="0"]

Ref: [woocommerce display categories/subcategories/products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764430/woocommerce-display-categories-subcategories-products)